# Export reminders from osx Reminders app programmatically

Tags: macos, applescript, reminders

I need to get reminders list in any form (could parse it later) from Reminders app in osx (10.9.1)

I know that i could do it from menu, but i need it programmatically.

Perfectly it would be some console command or script. Maybe there is a common way to interact with osx apps visual interface (not so good, but ok). It is needed for personal use.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Automator. Open Automator and:

1. Create a workflow
2. Add a “**Find Calendar Items**” action and add it
3. Change the first line from “Find *events* where:” to “Find *reminders* where:”
4. To grab *all* the reminders change the “**Any Content** contains **______**” to “**Title** **is not** **______**“ and leave the text field empty. You may need to change to fit your needs better.
5. Then add an “**Event Summary**” action underneath it.
6. From here you can use Automator to do whatever you like with the reminders.

To help you test it out, use a “**View Results**” action. You can insert it anywhere and it will show you what the output of the prior action was.

---

For doing this from Terminal:

1. Find the **.workflow** file you saved and copy the path to it.
2. Run `automator` and pass in the path.
3. Now you should see the results or errors of running the actions.

You will need to run this manually once to enable Terminal to prompt for access to your Reminders.

See also: [Automator: Find Reminders by list?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162808/automator-find-reminders-by-list)