# Automator: Find Reminders by list?

Tags: macos, automator, calendar, reminders, automation

I would like to retrieve all the Reminders in a specific reminders list with Automator. Searching for reminder, the available actions are “*Delete Reminders*”, “*New Reminders Items*”, “Filter Calendar Items“ and “Find Calendar Items”.

*Find Calendar Items* allows you to search for reminders, but the search parameters available are

- Title
- Notes
- Priority
- Completed
- URL
- Date Due
- Date last modified
- Date completed
- Reminder has (alarms)
- Reminder has no (alarms)

The “Reminder has (no)” query is fixed on alarms, no other options are given.

**Is there any way to get all the Reminders from a given list?**

I’m running Yosemite and Automator 2.5.

Comment: grab all reminders that have a date last updated greater than some time in the distant past.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround. In that list, let’s call it Downloads, I have put the word “downloads” in every reminder item. Like so:

#### Downloads

- Download http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/10/os-x-10-10/24/#javascript-automation
- Download https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/

Redundant and not too pretty, but it works.

The way I accomplished this was the following actions:

1. **Find Calendar Items**

   1. Find *Reminders* where
   2. *All* of the following are true
   3. *Any content* contains *`list_name`*
2. **Event Summary**
3. …Now you can run other actions like “Extract URLs from Text“

Then you’re done.

---

One thing I have learned is that (so far) there is no way to retrieve the contents of a list from Reminders. These actions will grab any item that has the text of the list name. It won’t grab that list (or all the contents) even though the list has the stirng I am searching for. It makes sense but it is lacking a bit.

Answer (score 0):

To show a specific reminder list in the app you can use JXA.

```
var Reminders = Application("Reminders")
Reminders.activate()
Reminders.lists.byName('List 1').show()
```

If you want to get the text of all reminders in a list you can use

```
Application('Reminders').lists.byName('List 1').reminders.whose({completed: false}).name()
```

To pull information out I used https://leancrew.com/all-this/2017/08/my-jxa-problem/

otherwise you can find more JXA snippets https://github.com/SeamlessIO/JXA-Snippets